# basic thing that I always get confuse about

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

LEt $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

if $a - b < \epsilon $

Why does it follow that $a = b $ ???

This bothers me a lot. Why does it follow? shouldn't be $a < b $ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\epsilon>0$ and $a-b<\epsilon$, then all you have is $a<b+\epsilon$.
If you have this for *all* positive $\epsilon$, then necessarily $a\le b$ (otherwise you could take $\epsilon=b-a$).
You do not get $a=b$, however, unless the condition actually reads $|a-b|<\epsilon$.